# Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'A'.ts(2339) - React, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Error:

> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'A'.ts(2339)

Here is my source code

```
export default class A extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.ref = React.createRef(); << ERROR HERE
```

How can I define type of `A` to resolve the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare the `ref` variable in the class body.

```
export default class A extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
   ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

   constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);

      this.ref = React.createRef();
   }
}
```

or basically remove the constructor and move logic outside.

```
export default class A extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  ref = React.createRef();
```

Comment: Thanks kind user. What's the type of `ref`? It shows me another issue on `ref;`

Comment: @hellofanengineer The type of ref is the component it refers to. `React.createRef<YourComponent>();`

Comment: you're very kind :D